# How to implement Having Clause in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm New to SSRS.

Im trying to create a report where i need to group by [DATA Flag] column which is working fine ,but once the data is grouped i need to set the DATA FLAG ="TotalCancellations" and there is another column CancellDays which i need to set it as <120 .
I tried

Option 1:-

So to achieve this i have added TWO filters one with 
Expression : DATA FLAG 
Operator =
and Value as TotalCancellations

and the other filter as follows

Expression : Cancelldays
Operator = 
and Value as < 120

But its not working and giving empty result,i have records with Cancelldays <120

Option 2 :-

Right click on Group and in General Tab ,Group on Expression as below ]

Fields!DFlag.Value = "TotalCancellations" AND Fields!DFlag.Value <120

which didnt work :(

this is similar to writing having clause in SQL i believe but im not getting how to implement that here in SSRS.

i can add in SQL Query but its already a huge query with lot of unions so please suggest me if there is any way i can implement here in SSRS

Im using Matrix in SSRS 2008

Comment: How can this statement, `Fields!DFlag.Value = "TotalCancellations" AND Fields!DFlag.Value <120` be valid? The DFlag can't be `TotalCancellations` AND `< 120` at the same time. Can you show some data?

Comment: You say your SQL query is large, but that generally isn't the case.  Can you please either add it to your answer or paste it somewhere like PasteBin and add a link?  Filtering like this should wherever possible be done in your SQL query for efficiency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the syntax for your option 1 is probably the easiest solution. In the Group Properties, under the Filters section, enter these two filters:

- Expression: [DFlag] (Text)

  - Operator: =
  - Value = TotalCancellations
- Expression: `=Sum(Fields!CancelDays.Value)` [enter this in the expression builder] (Integer)

  - Operator: <
  - Value: 120

Putting all the filters in a single expression, like your option 2, can be useful if you need to filter by one criteria OR another.

[image: Group Properties: Filters window]

Comment: i tried your filter expression but unfortunately it didn work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Below are the filer expressions

[image: filter expression]

and this is how group by is

[image: group by]

Answer (score 0):

The filter should be implemented at the tablix level, not at the group level.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)